# Turn detection on android

Tags: navigation, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I would like develop a turn by turn navigation app, and I use osmdroid and osmbonuspack lib.  currently I can get the road from routing services, but I dont have a solution for making a turn detection based on GPS Location, like when I arrived the intersection, then the app should show the instructions.

dose someone has experience on this field? pls give me some guidance, thank you very much.

Comment: Compare your current position against the route from the routing service?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question you are asking how to calculate an itinerary for a desired location.

I would suggest you follow the OSMBonusPack tutorials [here](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1), it should provide you the help you need.